# When using Select-Object and further writing to the .csv file using Export-CSV, can I not specify the column name?

Tags: performance, powershell, csv

Problem: 1) "$FileName" in string, 2) recording 7000+ files took over an hour. How do I make the recording faster?

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\*.csv" | ForEach-Object {
$CSV = Import-CSV -Path $_.FullName
    $FileName = $_.Name

    $CSV | Select-Object *,@{N='Filename';E={$FileName}} | Export-CSV $_.FullName
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to speed this up with PowerShell code alone is to resort to **plain-text processing**:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\*.csv | ForEach-Object {  
  $fileName = $_.Name
  $toAppend = ',"Filename"'
  $isHeaderRow = $true
  $lines = switch -File $_.FullName {
    default {
      $_ + $toAppend  # append to the line and output
      if ($isHeaderRow) {
        $isHeaderRow = $false
        $toAppend = ',"{0}"' -f $fileName
      }
    }
  }
  # Write the updated lines back to the file.
  # Adjust the -Encoding argument as needed.
  Set-Content $_.FullName -Value $lines -Encoding utf8 -WhatIf 
}
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note:

- The [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement with the `-File` parameter is an efficient way to process a text file line by line.
- Note that the array of updated lines, `$lines`, is passed to **`Set-Content`** via the `-Value` parameter, which is much faster than using the pipeline (`$lines | Set-Content ...`)
- The code assumes that a single CSV file can fit into memory as a whole; if that's not possible, you'd have to switch to a pipeline-based solution, which would slow things down:
  `& { switch ... } | Set-Content ...`

---

**Variation**, where all **input files have the same column structure** and are to be **merged into a single output file:**

```
$outFile = './out.csv' # single output file
$null = New-Item $outFile # initialize it (create it empty)

$firstFile = $true
Get-ChildItem C:\*.csv | ForEach-Object {  
  $fileName = $_.Name
  $isHeaderRow = $true
  $lines = switch -File $_.FullName {
    default {
      if ($isHeaderRow) {
        $isHeaderRow = $false
        if ($firstFile) {
          $firstFile = $false
          $_ + ',"Filename"' # output single header row
        }        
        # Construct string to append to this file's data rows.
        $toAppend = ',"{0}"' -f $fileName
      } else { # data row
        $_ + $toAppend # append to the line and output
      }
    }
  }
  # Append this file's updated lines to the output file.
  # Adjust the -Encoding argument as needed.
  Add-Content $outFile -Value $lines -Encoding utf8 -WhatIf 
}
```

Comment: @Andrei If you want to speed it up even further you could process the files in parallel, each in a seperate [job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob?view=powershell-7&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-5.1) or [runspace](https://learn-powershell.net/2012/05/13/using-background-runspaces-instead-of-psjobs-for-better-performance/)